# Uploading a small text file to OneDrive API / MS Graph

Tags: postman, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

What's the right content schema/format or protocol to use to upload a small text file to OneDrive? I'm authenticating correctly, etc., but the docs don't seem to work...

__

I'm following the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), exactly - and for sanity check - using Postman.

Specifically, this example from the docs:

```
PUT /me/drive/root:/FolderA/FileB.txt:/content
Content-Type: text/plain

The contents of the file goes here.
```

Error: "Entity only allows writes with a JSON Content-Type header.",

--

So I tried putting the body in a json and changing the content-type to json. **I'm actually not sure what the right json schema is...**

Error: "Property file in payload has a value that does not match schema."

--

I tried fiddling a bit with `PUT /me/drive/root:/FolderA/tester.txt:/content`

```
{ 
  "name": "tester.txt",
  "file":  { } 
}
```

But got Error: The name in the provided oneDrive.item does not match the name in the URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that the : needs to be at the end of the file path...

Previously, I had tried using `/me/drive/root:/FolderA:/FileB.txt:/content` instead of `/me/drive/root:/FolderA/FileB.txt:/content`